# Create function REGEX for optimization

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've been asked to optimize the speed of my query. I currently have this regex in my query, which is checking for a pattern and returning substring within that pattern. To clarify I have a table with multiple columns that I have to look through to check for this value: `[v=` and return the numbers within that list.

This is looking through several `'name..'` columns that look something like this: `xyzzy [v=123]` but I only want to return 123, the below works:

```
COALESCE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '[[]v=([0-9]+)', 1, 1, 'ie'),
REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME_5, '[[]v=([0-9]+)', 1, 1, 'ie'), 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME_4, '[[]v=([0-9]+)', 1, 1, 'ie')) as display_vertical_code
```

but to optimize this, I thought of maybe creating a function unfortunately I don't know javascript :/ and I don't know if the formatting is correct I'm having some difficulties creating it, this is what I've tried, can someone tell me if I'm missing something?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dfp.regex(NAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS OBJECT
LANGUAGE javascript 
STRICT AS '
return new RegExp(NAME,"[[]v=([0-9]+)",1 ,1,"ie")
';
```

When I try to use the above function in my below query:

```
    COALESCE(
        GET(DFP.REGEX(NAME)),
        GET(DFP.REGEX(NAME_5)),
        GET(DFP.REGEX(NAME_4)),
        GET(DFP.REGEX(NAME_3)),
        GET(DFP.REGEX(NAME_2)),
        GET(DFP.REGEX(NAME_1)),
        GET(DFP.REGEX(NAME_0))
) as display_vertical_code
```

I see this error:

> error line 3 at position 8 not enough arguments for function
> [GET(REGEX(Tablename.NAME))], expected 2, got 1

Comment: Why not concatenate the columns before extracting the substring? That way you won't have to do it for every column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION regex(NAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE javascript 
STRICT IMMUTABLE AS
$$
    const regex = /[[]\s{0,5}v\s{0,5}=\s{0,5}([0-9]+)/i;
    let s = NAME.match(regex);
    if (s != null) {
        return s[0].split('=')[1].trim();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
$$;


select regex('xyzzy [v=123]');

-- Alternate permutation
select regex('xyzzy [ v = 123]');
```

You want to return a string, not an object. Adding the IMMUTABLE option tells Snowflake that the same input results in the same output every time. It can sometimes help with performance.

Edit... This one's a bit more fault tolerant and allows whitespace (if that could be a problem). If you want to get rid of allowing whitespace, delete the `\s{0,5}` expressions.

Comment: Thanks for responding Greg! A few questions. 1. What is the purpose of the $$ in the beginning and the end of the function creation? 2. what is '/ig' at the end of the const regex? 3. for this: return s.toString().split('=')[1].trim();  could you explain this a bit, what is trim doing and toString?

Comment: The `$$` is an alternate string terminator in Snowflake. It makes it easier to type JavaScript code (including with SQL statements in stored procedures) by terminating the body of the code using `$$`. The `ig` specifies options for case insensitive and global. `trim` is eliminating whitespace, if any, on the 123 part that it's returning. `toString` is converting a JavaScript object to a string. The return of the `match` function is actually an array because match can return multiple results. In retrospect, you're only ever going to use the first match so `s[0]` is a better option. I'll update.